# Error in tensorflow for R example

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, rstudio

I am new to Tensorflow. I heard really great things about the tensorflow interface to R. I am however finding it difficult to run example listed here: https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tensorflow/articles/examples/linear_regression_multiple.html

The specific problem is in the following lines

```
while (TRUE) {
+     session$run(optimizer, feed_dict = feed_dict)
+     current_cost <- session$run(cost, feed_dict = feed_dict)
+     if (last_cost - current_cost < epsilon) break
+     last_cost <- current_cost
+ }
```

This throws the following error :

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  TypeError: Fetch argument <tensorflow.python.training.gradient_descent.GradientDescentOptimizer object at 0x126eaaf50> of <tensorflow.python.training.gradient_descent.GradientDescentOptimizer object at 0x126eaaf50> has invalid type <class 'tensorflow.python.training.gradient_descent.GradientDescentOptimizer'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a GradientDescentOptimizer into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

The only thing I have changed from the above example is :

> tf$global_variables_initializer

to

> tf$initialize_all_variables

Anyone faced similar error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialize_all_variables API has been deprecated in tensorflow (and was removed on 2017-03-02) , the correct API to use is global_variables_initializer

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initialize_all_variables

Comment: I might have an old version. Because when I run it i get: 

Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'global_variables_initializer'